# Are location-based lock screen app suggestions automatic in ios?

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store, lockscreen

Anyone know if there is anything you have to do as a developer of an app to get your app to be suggested form the lock screen in iOS 8 (I'm talking about when the app isn't installed, so it takes you to the app store)?  The only information I've been able to find about this is speculative at best -- most seem to conclude that this is either based off of the "apps near me" that the app store has, or direct arrangements made with Apple.  Anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Passbook

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW53